# Find the acute angles of a right angled triangle

Tags: trigonometry

In a right angled triangle one cathete is 20% longer that the other cathete. Find out the sizes of acute angles. Please help, i have a test tomorrow and its very important.

Comment: *Cathete* is a brand new term for me.  (Google keeps thinking I'm searching for *catheter*.)

Comment: It might be helpful if you share your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: @John \\ [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathetus?wprov=sfla1 ]

Answer (score 1):

The catheti are $a$ and $1.2a$ so the tangents of the angles are $\frac{1.2a}{a}=1.2=\frac{6}{5}$ and $\frac{a}{1.2a}=\frac{5}{6}$ so the angles are $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)\approx 50.19^\circ$ and $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)\approx 39.81^\circ$